# Add an attribute to a specific tag in text body of page

Tags: theming, entities

I would like to add an attribute to a specific **tag** in the text **body** of a page.

I was thinking in this direction:

- add `MYTHEME_preprocess_field(&$variables)` to **template.php**
- apply regular expression to the right field (but which one? `$variables['items'][0]['safe_value']`?)

Can anyone give me a specific working example of applying a regular expression to the body field of a page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are just looking to add an attribute to a **tag**, you could do your changes to the field `#markup` instead. A simple example:

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_field().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['element']['#field_name'] == 'body') {
    $markup = preg_replace('/href=/', 'title="foo" href=', $variables['items']['0']['#markup']);
    $variables['items']['0']['#markup'] = $markup;
  }
}
```